# NodeJS Set Timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, dom-events, settimeout

I'm using the phidgets library to interact with physical devices via nodejs. I've got it all connected physically, all I want to do is ensure my timings for the on/off's are precise.

This would be the issue, as I can't even get things to console.log out properly regarding setTimout's.

Essentially, I'm attempting to do the following:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    setTimeout( function(i){
        console.log('Input: "' + i + '", Executed with timeout of ' + i*1000 + 'ms');
    }(i), i*1000 );
};
```

But my console just spits out the below, with no timeouts. It's instant.

```
Input: "0", Executed with timeout of 0ms
Input: "1", Executed with timeout of 1000ms
Input: "2", Executed with timeout of 2000ms
Input: "3", Executed with timeout of 3000ms
```

Which is far from what I want.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the function in your setTimeout call because of the `(i)`

Change it to

```
setTimeout( function(i){
            console.log('Input: "' + i + '", Executed with timeout of ' + i*1000 + 'ms');
        }, i*1000, i );
```

This way you are passing the function 'pointer' into the setTimeout setup with the argument `i`

PS: All arguments after the time value `i*1000` will be passed as arguments to your callback function

Comment: Hey Rishi, Thanks a lot for that, it works perfectly. Can I ask what the difference between adding (i) to the end of the function is (as scope) and within the setTimeout function is, regarding execution order?

I don't quite understand why it wasn't waiting still.

Comment: well when you put `()` after a function it will run it (yes, even ones you have just defined)
So what will happen is the function will run during the loop itself and return value will be passed to the setTimeout, `undefined` in this case, hence it will run immediately during the loop, and the `undefined` will go to the timeout